# How to make the React Native Gifted Chat icon change if the chat isn't sent to server?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, chat, react-native-gifted-chat

I use react native gifted chat, and I want that when a user fails to send a chat to the server then the icon in the bubble changes?

Maybe if a user fails to send a message, an icon like this will appear:

[image]

Thank you, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it was a long time ago, but maybe it can help someone. If you are using Hooks and your messages array is defined like this `const [messages, setMessages] = useState();`

So, when tap on Send, you can add a new message to your state. Important to add `pending` and `sent` properties like

```
yourMessage.pending = true;
yourMessage.sent = false;
```

So, when you have the backend response, you can update

```
yourMessage.pending = false;
yourMessage.sent = true;
```

Finally, update the message state

```
setMessages(previousMessages => {
    const index = previousMessages.findIndex(aMessage => aMessage._id == yourMessage._id);
    const newArr = [...previousMessages];
    newArr[foundIndex] = yourMessage;
    return newArr;
});
```